# Cannot stitch many images using Stitcher class in opencv c++

Tags: opencv, image-processing, image-stitching, opencv-stitching

I want to stitch many images ( 25 ) in one single image of a straight surface of plastic part. Images look like this:

[image]  [image] [image] [image]

I am trying to use the Stitcher class form opencv. My code is here:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include <opencv2/stitching.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

bool try_use_gpu = false;
vector<Mat> imgs;
string result_name = "result.jpg";
Mat img1, img2,img3,img4,img5,img6,img7, pano;

void printUsage();
//int parseCmdArgs(int argc, char** argv);

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    // Load images from HD.
    img1 = imread("1.bmp");
    img2 = imread("2.bmp");
    img3 = imread("3.bmp");
    img4 = imread("4.bmp"); 

    // Put images into vector of images "imgs".
    imgs.push_back(img1);
    imgs.push_back(img2);
    imgs.push_back(img3);
    imgs.push_back(img4);   

    // Create stitcher instance and use stitch method with imgs.
    Stitcher stitcher = Stitcher::createDefault(try_use_gpu);
    stitcher.setPanoConfidenceThresh(0.8);
    Stitcher::Status status = stitcher.stitch(imgs, pano);

    if (status != Stitcher::OK)
    {
        cout << "Can't stitch images, error code = " << status << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    imwrite(result_name, pano);

    return 0;
}
```

I Always get an error saying : "Can't stitch images, error code = 1" so the system is saying that it needs more images. When debugging I see that images are properly loaded and then, vector imgs properly created. What can be the reasons? My calcuclation also last quite long (2 s)...

Comment: Can you tell the size of your images?

Comment: IMHO the Stitcher is bit of an overkill for your input. Assuming the images are in order, they are undistorted and the camera is moving in consistent direction along one axis, you can leverage this. You could use template matching to find the overlapping sections of adjacent images and use this to make a composite image. Simplest way would be to just concatenate the non-overlapped parts. Alternately do some blending on the parts that do overlap. | However, ideal approach would be to eliminate the need to do this altogether -- a line camera + some encoder.

Comment: @skoda23 A very simple [prototype in Python](http://pastebin.com/dMfGfyJ1), that generates [this result](http://i.imgur.com/2bSw2dj.png). You can add some vertical "wiggle space" in case the slices don't line up as nicely as in your apparently synthetic example. Also add some blending of the overlapping parts, either just half-half using `addWeighted`, or using a gradient for the weights.

Comment: BTW, it would be handy if you could provide a full set of 25 images, so we can make some meaningful comparisons.

Comment: @shawshank The size of the image is about 600 X 400 (depends on application) but not more. The type of camera used is Basler Aca1300 60gm (mono)

Comment: @Dan Mašek : Is there any code example written in C++ ? The result from python looks very good. Also quality of image is noot so bad, since I'm tending to lost as less image quality as possible with processing. Is there any good example how can I use template matching to make a composite image in c++ ? I cannot see solution using template matching currently...

Comment: Ok, I see you already [started porting it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905338/simple-stitching-in-c-using-opencv) :) I'll have a look when I've got some time.

Comment: @DanMašek, thats super! ;) I look forward that we will solve that code transfering from pyton to c++ ! I would be also happy if you can comment python code a bit...

Comment: @skoda23 [Here's a rough c++ implementation](http://pastebin.com/8qHCmfyE), with support for some vertical misalignment, to get you going. I'll comment both the python and c++ code and write up some answers tomorrow.

Comment: @DanMašek thats great. I currently don't now how to use this "rought c++ implementation" but I will try it today. Also check my c++ implementation of Python code: [link] http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42905338/simple-stitching-in-c-using-opencv [/link] . I will be very happy of your comments.

Answer (score 2):

The stitcher module of OpenCV uses images features to create an exact alignment. 

As a thumb rule, there should be around 20-30% overlap between the two images that have to be stitched. If there is no significant overlap between the camera fields, you won't have enough features between the image intersections. The images that you have given have quite a uniform background for the stitcher module to find sufficient features in the image intersection. You will need to look at increasing the features in the image intersection in order to align the images.

Comment: What If I cannot inrease the number of features? What can be the aplternative approaches to make composite image of my area? Should I use somekind of template matching?Note that I don't have much experiance with template matching.

Comment: I'd recommend trying to change the camera angle to increase the overlap between the images or try change the background of the white portion. Since you are unable to increase the number of features template matching would also not give good results.